# Field calculator to automatically update fields in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, arcgis-10.5

Trying to get an attribute table to update based on the values in their corresponding rows. for example - If I have a selection of fields whose value is 3, I want the corresponding fields to auto populate for that value, in this case road surface types.

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.

Comment: What program are you using? And what have you tried so far to accomplish this yourself?

Comment: domains and subtypes will be your best bet

Comment: The Field Calculator Toolbar a code-block option.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to update a field based on the value of another field in ArcGIS you can do something like this in Python in the field calculator where !STATUS! is replaced with the name of the field that the reclassification is based on.

Expression:

```
reclass(!STATUS!)
```

Code Block:

```
def reclass(STATUS):
                if STATUS == 0:
                                STATUS = "Road Type A"
                elif STATUS == 1:
                                STATUS = "Road Type B"
                elif STATUS == 2:
                                STATUS = "Road Type C"
                else:
                                STATUS = "error"
                return STATUS
```